# Javascript place elements in div

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the following code to show two specific elements, based on the toggleCompanyField function.

But I want to change this code and place those two elements inside a new div with `class='new-div'` and display/hide that specific new div instead of my current code.

How can I achieve that?

```
define([
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select',
    'uiRegistry'
], function (Select, registry) {
    'use strict';

    return Select.extend({
        defaults: {
            skipValidation: false
        },

        initialize: function () {
            this._super();

            this.toggleCompanyField()
        },

        onUpdate: function () {
            this._super();

            this.toggleCompanyField()
        },

        toggleCompanyField: function () {
            registry.get('checkout.steps.shipping-step.shippingAddress.shipping-address-fieldset.company', function(field){
                if (field.visible()) {
                    field.hide()
                } else {
                    field.show()
                }
            });
            registry.get('checkout.steps.shipping-step.shippingAddress.shipping-address-fieldset.fax', function(field){
                if (field.visible()) {
                    field.hide()
                } else {
                    field.show()
                }
            });
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: `registry.` object? Not really sure how you expect anyone to help you move divs to another whatever if there's no HTML....?

Comment: please html code as well

Comment: @zer00ne I just updated the code.

Comment: @NagaSaiA I just updated the code